# Frameless window in shoes

Tags: shoes

Is there a way to make a frameless window with shoes on Windows?
I searched a lot and couldn't find anything that helps me.
The only thing i found was someone saying he could make it with the win32api years ago, but my research in that results in nothing.

edit 
It looks like that it is possible with SetWindowLong from the win32api, but i cant figure out how exactly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this in Shoes that I'm aware of, you'd have to get straight tot he win32 api which would mean modifying the C-code of shoes3.

For shoes4 there is [an open issue](https://github.com/shoes/shoes4/issues/1052) for the wished behavior.